# Passing Data from a View Controller to a First Detail Controller and then to a Second Detail Controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, controller

Posting my first question here on stackoverflow! Hope my question is clear, here it is...

I have a Navigation Controller embedded in a First View Controller that has a table view. From the table view I have a segue that pushes to a First Detail Controller. Everything works fine, the segue passes the data to the First Detail Controller, however I would like to push again from a button to a Second Detail Controller.

The layout in the storyboard looks like this [Image of storyboard](http://fracchia.org/more_detail.png)

I set-up a Second Detail Controller and pushed to that from a button on the First Detail Controller.
However I can not figure out how to pass the data I have in an array along to the Second Detail Controller. I added an NSLog line to see what was being passed along and the debug panel is outputing "**(null)**"

Here is my viewdidload and segue code from the .m First View Controller named ColorBookViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    Color *color1 = [Color new];
    color1.name = @"Red";
    color1.hexnumber = @"FF0000";
    color1.spanishname =@"Rojo";

    Color *color2 = [Color new];
    color2.name = @"Green";
    color2.hexnumber = @"00FF00";
    color2.spanishname =@"Verde";


    Color *color3 = [Color new];
    color3.name = @"Blue";
    color3.hexnumber = @"0000FF";
    color3.spanishname = @"Azul";

    colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: color1,color2,color3, nil];
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {
   if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showColorDetail"]) {
       NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
       ColorDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
       destViewController.color = [colors objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       }
}
```

Here is the view did load from the .m of the First Detail Controller named ColorDetailController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"This is...%@", color.name);
    self.nameLabel.text = color.name;
    self.hexnumberLabel.text = color.hexnumber;
}
```

My .h for the SecondDetailController:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Color.h"

@interface SecondDetailViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UILabel *spanishnameLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Color *color;

@end
```

Here is the view did load from the .m of the Second Detail Controller named SecondDetailController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = color.name;
    NSLog(@"This is...%@", color.spanishname);
    self.spanishnameLabel.text = color.spanishname;
}
```

The app runs fine in the simulator, but I get a blank screen for the Second Detail Controller and I get the "null" result from NSLog(@"This is...%@", color.spanishname);

Any suggestions as to why the segue passes and holds the instance for the first Detail View but not the Second Detail View? Or am I missing something more fundamental here? I tried setting up a second segue on the First Detail Controller and the NSLog produces the correct result (the color name in Spanish), but I am not sure how I would pass this onto the Second Detail Controller:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showMoreDetail"]) {

        NSLog(@"This is... %@",color.spanishname);  //works fine
        self.spanishnameLabel.text = color.spanishname;  //throws error 
        }
}
```

Thanks for any help or insight!

[Download the complete project here](http://fracchia.org/doubleDetail.zip)

Comment: You pass the object in your colors array to `Color` in the second VC. What is `Color`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass the data to the second ViewController, just do exactly the same thing as you did in the first ViewController: pass the reference of the `Color` object in the segue.

In the `SecondDetailViewController`, you already have a color property. You just have to set this property with the same `Color` object that was selected in your `ColorBookViewController`. As you already have this reference in the `ColorDetailViewController`, just pass it directly to the `SecondDetailViewController`, via segue.

Inside your `ColorDetailViewController`:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
   if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showMoreDetail"]) {
       SecondDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
       destViewController.color = self.color;
   }
}
```

Now, in the `viewDidLoad` of the `SecondDetailViewController`, you would be able to set the labels correctly, like in `self.spanishnameLabel.text = color.spanishname;`